# Can't figure out how to boot from Windows installation media on /dev/sdb2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on a separate partition alongside Ubuntu. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Download Unetbootin and GParted
2. Use GParted to create 2 partitions, `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` on my USB
3. Use Unetbootin to extract a GParted Live ISO to `/dev/sdb1`
4. Use GParted Live to split my root partition on `/dev/sda` in half, making room for Windows
5. Extracted the Windows 10 ISO to `/dev/sdb2`

Now when I restart my computer and go to BIOS, there is no option to boot from `/dev/sdb2`. The Boot Sequence options are only "UEFI SanDisk, Partition 1" and "ubuntu". How do I go about getting it to boot from the 2nd partition on my USB drive?

Comment: How to boot the Windows installer in an unusual way seems like a Windows support question.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS boot system & Ubuntu install? You then want Windows in same boot mode. But Windows only boots in BIOS  mode from a primary NTFS partition with boot flag. And only in UEFI boot mode from gpt partitioned drive. And installers boot from FAT32 formatted partition, normally first partition with boot flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)